# Modeling Cardinality of Finite Sets in Coq

Tags: coq

I have made a basic theory of finite sets in Coq.

### Syntax of Finite Sets (fsets)

An `fset_expr` can be
the empty set, an add operation,
a filter (set comprehension) of another set,
a cup (union) of two sets,
or a cap (intersection) of two sets.

```
 Inductive fset_expr { A : Set } : Set :=
| fset_expr_empty : fset_expr
| fset_expr_add : fset_expr -> A -> fset_expr
| fset_expr_filter : fset_expr -> (A -> bool) -> fset_expr
| fset_expr_cup : fset_expr -> fset_expr -> fset_expr
| fset_expr_cap : fset_expr -> fset_expr -> fset_expr.
```

### Semantics of Set Membership

`in_fset s a` means that the `s : fset_expr` contains the member `a`.

```
Inductive in_fset { A : Set } : fset_expr (A:=A) -> A -> Prop :=
| in_fset_add : forall x a, in_fset (fset_expr_add x a) a
| in_fset_added : forall x a0 a1, in_fset x a0 -> in_fset (fset_expr_add x a1) a0
| in_fset_cup_l : forall x y a, in_fset x a -> in_fset (fset_expr_cup x y) a
| in_fset_cup_r : forall x y a, in_fset y a -> in_fset (fset_expr_cup x y) a
| in_fset_cap : forall x y a, in_fset x a -> in_fset y a -> in_fset (fset_expr_cap x y) a
| in_fset_filter : forall x f a, in_fset x a -> (f a = true) -> in_fset (fset_expr_filter x f) a.
```

### Subsets and Set Equality

```
Definition is_empty_fset {A : Set} (s : fset_expr (A:=A))  :=
  forall a, ~(in_fset s a).

Definition subset_fset {A : Set} (x y : fset_expr (A:=A)) :=
  forall a, in_fset x a -> in_fset y a.

Definition eq_fset {A : Set} (x y : fset_expr (A:=A)) :=
  subset_fset x y /\ subset_fset y x.
```

### Cardinality

This is where complications occured. I defined `cardinality_fset s n` which is supposed to mean that the finite set `s : fset_expr` contains `n : nat` elements.

```
Inductive cardinality_fset { A : Set } : fset_expr (A:=A) -> nat -> Prop :=
| cardinality_fset_empty : cardinality_fset fset_expr_empty 0
| cardinality_fset_add : forall s n a,
    ~(in_fset s a) ->
    cardinality_fset s n ->
    cardinality_fset (fset_expr_add s a) (S n)
| cardinality_fset_trans :
    forall x y n,
      eq_fset x y ->
      cardinality_fset x n ->
      cardinality_fset y n.
```

### Problem

I could not prove that cardinality is well defined, i.e. every congruence class of `fset_expr` under relation `eq_fset` has a unique cardinality. Is it possible?

```
  forall s : fset_expr (A:=A), exists n, (cardinality_fset s n /\ forall s' n', eq_fset s s' -> cardinality_fset s' n' -> n' = n).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove that theorem, you need to be able to write a function `cardinality : fset_expr -> nat` that computes the cardinality of a finite set, and to do that, you will need to decide whether or not two elements `(a1 a2 : A)` are equal (so that you don't double-count).

If you include an assumption `forall a1 a2 : A, {a1 = a2} + {a1 <> a2}`, then your theorem should be provable.

Comment: I see that the `cardinality` function is necessary and sufficient for the proof.

Is it possible to implement such a function even without your equality assumption? Or is such an assumption absolutely necessary?

Comment: Assuming the cardinality function existed, to know whether two elements `a1` and `a2` of `A` are equal, you would only need to compute the cardinal of `add a1 (add a2 empty)`.  So yes the two notions seem to be necessary for each other.